# Assign Base64 string to an image in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, binary

I already wasted a lot of time on a basic problem, I have a .cshtml razor view that  have a model of type DataTable and this datatable have some TableRows with one column that stores an image byte array. how can I assign this model value to an image element in the view. this is what I've came up so far.

```
 var binaryData = @Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Rows[0][0] as Byte[]);
    var img = document.getElementById('ImgEle')
                      .setAttribute('src', "data:image/jpg;base64," + binaryData);
```

I'm receiving this error at chrome console window : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags`

how can I fix this problem?

**Edit:**

Thanks to @hiltononline answer this is the code I'm ended up with and its working fine

```
var binaryData='@Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Rows[0][0] as Byte[])';
var img = document.getElementById("ImgEle");
img.setAttribute("src", "data:image/jpg;base64," + binaryData);
```

Hope this will help somebody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `binaryData` needs to  be wrapped in single quotes to be treated as a string:

`var binaryData='@Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Rows[0][0] as Byte[])';`

An alternative could be to insert the model value in the setAttribute method directly:

```
var img = document.getElementById("ImgEle");
img.setAttribute("src", "data:image/jpg;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Rows[0][0] as Byte[])");
```

Additionally, depending on how the data is stored, it may not need to be decoded again. You can double check the byte array is valid using an online decoder such as CodeBeautify's [base64-to-image-converter](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter)

Comment: the second is not working the same error message appear, the first option is correct and I have to check on the base64 if its valid.

Comment: I had checked on the base64 generated and its valid unfortunately the image not showing on the view any thoughts?

Comment: @VoiceOfTheRain If the image is not displaying, without additional information, my guess is that `binaryData` is an empty string or it is not formatted correctly.  Can you debug the javascript to find the `binaryData` value or inspect the img element and share the src?

Answer (score 0):

I only know about how to display a base64 image string as  tag in javascript so if your error is just at this level, good news — otherwise I cannot really help you with the first row (`binaryData`):

```
var binaryData = @Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Rows[0][0] as Byte[]);
var img = document.getElementById("ImgEle");
img.setAttribute("src", "data:image/jpg;base64," + binaryData);
```

I think you just forgot the name of the attribute (`src`) you wanted to set with `setAttribute` and that you messed up with the `img` variable assignation.

Comment: I've edited my question by mistake, the problem has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Just to make sure, there is another issue with your second line as you wrote `var img = ….setAttribute(…);` But `setAttribute` always returns `undefined` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute#Return_value — You have to split that line in two or to remove your assignment.

Comment: No idea about razor but javascript accepts both single and double quotes.

Comment: If the base64 conversion results in a string that contains `/`, that'd explain why the error is complaining about invalid regex.  Putting quotes around the razor (double or single) should fix that: `var binaryData = '@Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Rows[0][0] as Byte[])';`

Comment: @wjervis wrapping the razor with double quotes solve it however fell into another issue data:image/jpeg;base64,%C3%BF%C3%98%C3%BF%C3%A0%00%10JFIF%00%01%01%00%00%01%00%01%00%00%C3%BF%C3%9B%00C%00%08%06%06%07%06%05%08%07%07%07%09%09%08%0A%0C%14%0D%0C%0B%0B%0C%19%12%13%0F%14%1D%1A%1F%1E%1D%1A%1C%1C $.'A0%02%C2%8A(%C2%A0%02%C2%8A(%C2%A0%02%C2%8A(%C2%A0%02%C2%8A(%C2%A0%02%C2%8A(%C2%A0%02%C2%8A(%C2%A0%02%C2%8A(%C2%A0%02%C2%8A%00%08%06%06%07%06%05%08%07%07%07%09%09%08%0A%0C%14%0D%0C%0B%0B%0C%19%12%13%0F%14%1D%1A%1F%1E%1D%1A%1C%1C $.' ", net::ERR_INVALID_URL

Comment: Check the base 64 conversion, make sure that's generating the appropriate string